# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS from Nginx is not working

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

Type: https://example.com => **ssl ok**
But type: www.example.com and example.com is http **no redirect** https. (www redirect to non-www).

WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL): https//example.com

/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf

```
server {
listen 80; 
server_name example.com www.example.com;
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert_chain.crt;
#ssl_CACertificate_File /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.ca-bundle;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key; 
access_log off;
# access_log /home/example.com/logs/access_log;
error_log off;
# error_log /home/example.com/logs/error.log; 
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
root /home/example.com/public_html;
include /etc/nginx/conf/ddos2.conf;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name example.com;
```

How to fix it ?
Sorry my bad English, thank you.

Comment: did you enable the https support in your server config?

Comment: Yes, I did enable.

Answer (score 11):

This might be caused by the ambiguous server name indeed. Try using the following:

```
server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl; # Listen for SSL at port 443 as well

    # ... other config - certificates and such

    # If a user tries to come through http, redirect them through https
    if ($scheme != "https") { 
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}
```

You can check your nginx configuration by running `sudo nginx -t`.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar problem. It was caused by linux firewall (port 80 was disallowed).

Answer (score 1):

Your configuration is not clear, you have at the end a duplicated `server_name example.com` line.

Try to use this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: I try it, and deleted duplicate code `server_name example.com`. Restart nginx but my issue is still

Comment: `# service nginx restart
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
Stopping nginx:  [  OK  ]
Starting nginx: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "example.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored`

Comment: check that you only have one  `server { listen 80 ...` you could try by first just trying the block I put here and later enable the others, use `nginx -t` to test the config

Comment: Check only in /etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf ?

Comment: `nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Answer (score 0):

Update this line return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;

With return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

i have also the same problem with nginx so I apply these to server to accept only one request which will decide for both http and https

```
server { 
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    listen 443 ssl http2 ;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ;
    server_name example.com www.example.com; 

    #------ ssl certificates and other config --------

    set $https_redirect 0;
    #if request came from port 80/http
    if ($server_port = 80) { 
        set $https_redirect 1; 
    }
    # or if the requested host came with www 
    if ($host ~ '^www\.') { 
        set $https_redirect 1; 
    }
    #then it will redirects
    if ($https_redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
}
```

by using this I have only server block to hanlde any request

Answer (score 0):

If you have domain settings at

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

or you can have different files per the domain name at /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain.com.

```
 server {
    if ($host = www.domainname1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    if ($host = www.domainname2.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.domainname1.com www.domainname2.com;
    return 404;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This code will help you redirect to https:

Say you enter http://www.example.com, then it will redirect to https://www.example.com
,
if someone enters http:example.com, it will redirect to https://www.example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost_default_:443>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
SSLEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The code that you provided is for Apache HTTPD. This conversation is in regards to NGINX.